# multiple curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) in c#?

Tags: c#, crtp, recurring

Im trying to implement CRTP interface to my code, but the constraint make me stuck. how to implement the constraints if i have code structure look like this? Is this legal? Thank you.

```
interface IInterface<T>
    where T: IInterface<T>
{
    //bla bla bla
    T Member { get; set; }
}
interface ITest1<iTest2, iTest1> : IInterface<iTest2>
{
    //bla bla bla
}
interface ITest2<iTest1, iTest3> : IInterface<iTest1>
{
    iTest3 RefMember { get; set; }
    //bla bla bla
}
interface ITest3<iTest2>
{
    List<iTest2> manyTest { get; set; }
    //bla bla bla
}
class Test1 : ITest1<Test2, Test1>
{
    //bla bla bla
}
class Test2 : ITest2<Test1, Test3>
{
    //bla bla bla
}
class Test3 : ITest3<Test2>
{
    //bla bla bla    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? If it doesn't compile, what error are you getting?

Comment: that code is all wrong :) even if compiler allows it (`interface IInterface<T> where T : IInterface<T>` et al). I think you best explain what you want, structure you have.

Comment: @svick if the code written like that, i have no any error. But when i trying to adding the constraints, will make me headache .`ITest1<iTest2, iTest1> : Entity<iTest1> where iTest2 : ITest2<ITest1<iTest2,iTest1>,ITest3<ITest1<iTest2,iTest1>,..... (?????)`

Comment: @NSGaga i has reading Eric Lippert blog, he said :
> `class Blah<T> where T : Blah<T>`

> That appears to be circular in (at least) two ways. Is this really legal?

> Yes it is legal, and it does have some legitimate uses...
In my case, i has 2 player, each player has 10 pawns. And each pawn will be placed on a board size of 5 x 5. Every Point of my board has different move references. the mapping like this. Every pawn will copying move references from their point. http://thumbnails101.imagebam.com/25012/afd0fd250112805.jpg?nc

Comment: @user2277061 That doesn't sound like something you should model using the type system, I think.

Comment: I agree - it may be 'legit' in extreme cases (and compiles) - but you seem to have a tree like structure - and you may need a specific structure. But I don't see many `types` there, except for Pawn, Point, and not even what should be generic.

Comment: @svick Ya, thats all my wrong, i think i can connecting some object with same interface using that way. But i got many error. I think that i can create an interface, where they will have member as the same interface.

Comment: @NSGaga i must redesign my structure, i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public abstract class MyBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The my test method. divyang
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void MyVirtualMethodWhichIsOverridedInChild()
    {
        Console.Write("Method1 Call from MyBase");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The my another test method.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void MyAnotherTestMethod();

    /// <summary>
    /// The my best method.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void MyVirualMethodButNotOverridedInChild()
    {
        Console.Write("Method2 Call from MyBase");
    }
}
```

now make base class

```
public abstract class CrtpBaseWrapper<T> : MyBase
    where T : CrtpBaseWrapper<T>
{
}
```

then  you can  make your subclass

```
public class CrtpChild : CrtpBaseWrapper<CrtpChild>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The my test method. divyang
    /// </summary>
    public override void MyVirtualMethodWhichIsOverridedInChild()
    {
        Console.Write("Method1 Call from CrtpChild");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The my another test method.
    /// </summary>
    public override void MyAnotherTestMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("MyAnotherTestMethod Call from CrtpChild");
    }
}
```

Comment: finally i used your method. Thank you